Change the edit attribution
Today I found out this SE site and browsed a little. A question caught my interest and while reading the answer, I edited it to improve readability. The edit then went to the approval queue and after that I actually joined the site.
Now the edit is approved, but the attribution is to the "Community" user.
Is it possible to retroactively change the user to my proper username?
The intention is that the activity shows in my activity history view when looking at he profile.

Alas, this is not possible, sorry. There is no link between your edit (which was accepted before you joined) and your current account. 
But I'm sure you'll find other ways to improve the site now that you're a member :)
